# Connecting to Databricks account console using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to connect to databricks account console (not workspace) using powershell script. Could someone please share the powershell script for connecting to databricks account console using SPN credentials(client_id, client_secret or aad_token) for calling below api?

[https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net//api/2.0/accounts/{account_id}/scim/v2/Users](https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net//api/2.0/accounts/%7Baccount_id%7D/scim/v2/Users)

Method Post

https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/account/accountusers/create

Expecting a Powershell script code for connecting to account console

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/azure-powershell-login-service-principal

can you check this if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code SPN is connecting to azure account successfully. But need to know how we can connect to databricks account console?

```
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<Client-secret>" -AsPlainText -Force
$TenantId = "<Tenant-ID>"
$ApplicationId = "<Client-ID>"

$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ApplicationId, $SecurePassword

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential
```